# Magento 1.9.1 model extend not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add new method Mage_Eav_Model_Form, so I want to extend it. 
Doing as it suppose to be, but extension simply not working. 
Here is my part from config:

```
<models>
<vendor_mymodule>
    <class>Vendor_Mymodule_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>tw_subscriptionheader_resource</resourceModel>
</vendor_mymodule>
<vendor_mymodule_resource>
    <class>Vendor_Mymodule_Model_Resource</class>
</vendor_mymodule_resource>
<eav>
    <rewrite>
        <form>Venor_Mymodule_Model_Eav_Form</form>
    </rewrite>
</eav>
```

Here is original model:

```
abstract class Mage_Eav_Model_Form
```

And mine:

```
class Vendor_Mymodule_Model_Eav_Form extends Mage_Eav_Model_Form
```

For example I want to add:

```
public function something() {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract classes cannot be overridden. You'll need to override a non-abstract class that extends Mage_Eav_Model_Form instead.

See this answer for more info: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/52750/9276.

Comment: OK, I extended Mage_Customer_Model_Form, it extends that abstract class. Changed in config also. But still not working. Even PHPStorm doesn't link it. Don't get it what I am doing wrong.

Comment: $addressForm = $this->_getModel('customer/form'); PHPStorm on click on customer/form shows there is my extended class and file.
But here $addressErrors = $addressForm->validateAjaxData($addressData); , validateAjaxData is not visible, and it doesn't fire when needed.

Comment: Make sure your path in the XML is: `<global><models><customer><rewrite><form>`. Also try `echo get_class($addressForm)` to check whether another extension might already be overriding it.

Comment: It should be `validateData()`, not `validateAjaxData()`, unless you added that method yourself?

Comment: I added that method myself. 
There was another class from another module overriding it, tried to extend it, but still my function not starting. I added dependancy for that module, no luck. config.xml changed accordint to new extending, but nothing helps :(

Comment: Comment-out/remove the rewrite xml in the other extension's config.xml, but still extend that class, to keep its functionality.